# Python: Changing Windows Information Protection file ownership from "work" to "personal"

Tags: python, file, ownership

Everytime when I download a file from my company's SharePoint it changes the Windows Information Protection File Ownership to Work. I can't access the file in Python (Permission denied error).
I have to change the file ownership by right-clicking the file and set it to personal (Screenshot).

It's important that I automate this within my Python script. When I google / ChatGPT for solutions the answers are always about the security permissions of the file and that's not the same as the File ownership I have issues with.

Does anyone know how I can solve this?
Thanks in advance!

[image: File ownership]